# Chrome is redirected to the api url

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webpack

I have a config.json file:

```
{
    "api": "https://**.*****.nl/",
    "debug": true,
    "signalRTransports": "auto"
}
```

Sometimes in Chrome when I visit `http://localhost:8080` (served by webpack) I get redirected to the api url.

Currently I'm working with BackstopJS to setup a testing reference, but this doesn't work well when I get redirected. Does anyone know how to prevent the redirection?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which tool `config.json` is the configuration file for - it's not entirely clear to me from your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the problem was that I was redirected after being logged in to the API server. Passing the cookies that come with the API call seems to fix the problem of being redirected.